# Gradle Manifest Merger failed after adding compile RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

This error message popped up after being able to import RecyclerView. I can't find the source, or a fix. The error message seems pretty hard to follow as well.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>   Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.1) from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31
>       is also present at [com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-38 value=(26.0.0-alpha1).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:34 to override.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.me.listviewprojektfuerapp">

    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".ui.ListActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**build.gradle(module:app)** :

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.me.listviewprojektfuerapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
}
```

Comment: Obviously you should use the same version of recyclerview-v7 as other support library ... error is self-explanatory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1 and also com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1, recycler view is a part of appcompact library and hence the clash and also it is advisable to use same library versions

for more reference - https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile with this version of `recyclerView` 
`compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'`

Answer (score 0):

tools:replace="android:value"<==== put it on your in application attributes or you can make 2 version of both library to same version.